# Using Variable Names inside Functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, naming-conventions, naming, calling-convention

I am trying to add a column called "Lifespan" into the dataset in my workspace entitled "options_20020208".

I need to do this multiple times via a loop (Since there are multiple tables)

My problem is that I need to insert "Name" and have matlab process it as "options_20020208":

```
Name = options_20020208


Start = cellstr(Name(:,5))
End = cellstr(Name(:,3))

Start = datenum(Start)
End = datenum(End)

Lifespan = wrkdydif(Start,End)
Name.Lifespan = nominal(Lifespan)
```

I need to make it such that matlab reads the above code is read as :

```
Start = cellstr(options_20020208(:,5))
End = cellstr(options_20020208(:,3))

Start = datenum(Start)
End = datenum(End)

Lifespan = wrkdydif(Start,End)
options_20020208.Lifespan = nominal(Lifespan)
```

This is a fairly basic question, I know.. but I'm a newbie and not really sure how to approach it.

Any advice would help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Name_string = 'options_20020208';
eval([Name_string,'.Lifespan = nominal(Lifespan);']);
```

For a better answer, please show the exact line defining Name in your *actual* code.

Comment: I got it working, using the eval command on each Name_String. 

Thanks, that solves it!